# How to find different records of same model with Ember-Data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want to load two different sets of the same model from the server.

I tried it like this:

```
App.ProjectListRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Em.RSVP.hash({
      ownProjects: this.store.find('project',{owner: true}),
      projects: this.store.find('project')
    });
  }
})
```

This fires 2 requests to the server and the response has the right data.

But `{{each project in model.projects}}` in the template shows the same records as `{{each project in model.ownProjects}}`

Comment: Are the results of the store calls correct? (can you test to see if the store calls are returning the right data in the model hook). Small note: you are missing the return statement in the model hook above.

Comment: Sorry, ported the code from LiveScript. I will look into it. I just looked into the requests those calls created and the request/response data was right.

Comment: I had some problems with using `hash` as model in the past too, you could try to set the hash properties directly on the controller in the `setupController` hook. So `{{each project in model.projects}}` will than become `{{each project in projects}}`. But the question remains why your code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Object controller or Array controller?
I faced same problem in past. that time i Just changed my controller type from Array to Object and it worked.

and try printing the values of ownprojects and project in template with the help of {{log ownprojects}} helper to see what is getting returned from model to template.

Comment: Isn't the use of ObjectController deprecated?

Comment: Which ember version are you using?